# SSRS ExecutionLog not updating

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

We just recently updated our prod instanct to sql sp2.  since then the executionlog for ssrs hasn't updated except for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.  I need to get this running again because management is using a report based off of the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured out the problem.  The dns entry for the report server was pointed at the wrong instance, so the execution log wasn't updating because no executions were happening on that instance.